# Django - Image not saving from form

Tags: python, django, web-applications, django-file-upload

I am getting an error setting up this Django web app. I receive a 505 error message whenever I hit the submit button. The image is supposed to be saved in the root directory, but I can't seem to figure out the problem.

Below is the code for the web app

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from CancerClassifier import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('^$', views.index, name = 'homepage'),
    url('predictImage', views.predictImage, name='predictImage'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

def index(request):
    context = {'a' : 1}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def predictImage(request):
    print(request)
    print(request.POST.dict())
    fileObj = request.FILES['filePath']
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    fs.save(fileObj.name, fileObj)

    context = {'a' : 1}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Skin Lesion Classifier</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <h1>Upload new File</h1>

        <form class="imageUpload" action="predictImage" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="file" name="filePath">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <br>
            <h3>Prediction: {{prediction}}</h3>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the error message i received in the terminal:

```
[16/Jan/2021 17:13:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 493
<WSGIRequest: POST '/predictImage'>
{'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'UPYALDxVQ8SJR8DDy55h14PnaaWElXBwcYnlms6hhpV9qgbtdy1hW6UnU1Y8TVpk', 'filePath': 'image-asset.jpeg'}
Internal Server Error: /predictImage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sparshbohra/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 76, in __getitem__
    list_ = super().__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'filePath'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sparshbohra/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/sparshbohra/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/sparshbohra/cancer-scanner/CancerProj/CancerClassifier/views.py", line 12, in predictImage
    fileObj = request.FILES['filePath']
  File "/Users/sparshbohra/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 78, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'filePath'
[16/Jan/2021 17:13:19] "POST /predictImage HTTP/1.1" 500 67980
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was just missing the enctype in the HTML form.

Just added
enctype="multipart/form-data"
in the form tag